# Smaller elements on OpenUi5

Tags: sapui5

I would like to ask if there is any other way to make some openui5 elements smaller than the sizeCompact class. For example I have this, http://xrd-cache-1.t2.ucsd.edu/alja/tree3.html is there anyway to make the nodes smaller?

Answer (score 2):

If any of the [content density modes](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/d935dbf196d34997bf1ac42ac3e81579) is good for you, then you should [customize the controls with your own CSS](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/723f4b2334e344c08269159797f6f796)